# JSON Schema property for MaxLength of a number

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I have a requirement to restrict the Amount field which is of decimal type to have length of 12+4. i.e., max integer value can be 999999999999 whereas maximum number of fractional digits is 4. I am using NewtonSoft.JSON for schema validation.

I tried with the below schema but it does not seem to be working.

```
    {
    "type":"object",    
    "required":false,
    "properties":{
        "Product": {
            "type":"object",
            "required":false,
            "properties":{
                "Amount": {
                    "type":"number",
                    "required":true, 
                    "blank":false, 
                    "minLength":1, 
                    "maxDecimal":4 , 
                    "minimum":0, 
                    "maximum": 999999999999
                },
                "ProductID": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "required":false
                },
                "ProductType": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "required":false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please guide me here. Thanks in advance.

My input JSON string is as below,

```
{
  "Product": {
    "Amount": 888888888888.2222,
    "ProductType": "Notes",
    "ProductID": "GBPN"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON data is not correct format

Comment: I had just given an excerpt from my Schema. Now edited the question to provide complete schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Json-Schema docs:

3.2.  Validation of numeric instances

The JSON specification does not define any bounds to the scale or precision of numeric values. JSON Schema does not define any such bounds either. This means that numeric instances processed by JSON Schema can be arbitrarily large and/or have an arbitrarily large decimal part, regardless of the ability of the underlying programming language to deal with such data.

You will need to develop a custom validation for that. Be aware of Json.Net uses Json-Schema draft3.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON schema , minLength and maxLength only applies to string type properties.

Comment: Yeah, I just learned now. :(